# Listing SSRS instances on network

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I am looking for something similar to this:

```
var table = SqlDataSourceEnumerator.Instance.GetDataSources();
```

that lists Report Server (SSRS) instances on the network, rather than SQL server instances.

Is there a way to obtain such a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no way to verify that an endpoint is running ssrs by url, however, if you can enumerate server names on a network you could call a wmi function outlined [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0f5b5363-a154-412b-b6f3-ecbda8082377/how-do-i-get-all-instances-of-ssrs-installed-ona-server?forum=sqlreportingservices) to determine if the ssrs is running on that machine.

Comment: Thanks, what I was looking for :)